# Running home OpenVPN server with ISP blocking port forwarding

Tags: port-forwarding, openvpn

I want to run OpenVPN server at home to access my media server but my ISP blocks port forwarding.

Is there any way to punch holes through ISP's NAT?
Also, I thought of using VPS in the middle, which may help me overcome the problems of a dynamic IP. Any easy way to setup this?

Edit:
Here's a scheme of what I want to accomplish:

[image: Network scheme]

How can I obtain reverse connection to my OpenVPN server (Raspberry Pi) and use VPS for redirecting the traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a VPS, the solution is simple: It will host the VPN server and both your LAN and the “Road Warrior” will connect to it. That means you won’t have any *incoming* connections to your local network, only *outgoing* connections, which will always work.

Depending on the specifics, you may have to add firewall rules, routes or set up bridging on the “LAN” side.

On the VPN server, you’d set an appropriate configuration (like `topology subnet`, to simplify routing) including `client-to-client`.

Then, in the “Road Warrior”’s VPN configuration file, you’d include something like:

```
route <your subnet> 255.255.255.0 <LAN VPN client IP>
```

For example:

```
route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0 10.1.3.127
```

...where 10.1.3.127 is the IP address the machine currently called “VPN server” (on your local LAN) has inside the VPN.

If you want to access other machines in your local network they either need a route to the VPN, the machine formerly known as “VPN server” needs to do `MASQUERADE` or you need a bridged setup (which comes with additional trouble).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't forward traffic in to some service behind your router, or don't want to cope with changing IPs, then you are right to assume a VPS could be needed.

Indeed, you may use such as an OpenVPN server (or whatever VPN). Clients can connect as you connect a web page, without requiring any ports redirection on their side. From there, a third-party OpenVPN client *could* have access to its neighbors - granted the server permits it.

The easier way to do this would be to use OpenVPN with a single PSK identifying all your clients. Although this is also the less recommended: using distinct private keys identifying your clients is better, as "losing" a key is less critical to your setup.

On the other hand, if you're not familiar with certificates generation, you may need some patience and perseverance.

OpenVPN gives out several [howtos](https://openvpn.net/howto.html) and some [examples](https://openvpn.net/examples.html). You'll probably want to start there.

Comment: Actually, I know how to use OpenVPN. I have troubles with setting it up on my home network, so that I can access my 'media server' containing photos, movies, etc. on the go and having the ability to connect to internet through my home connection.